# UniswapV3 analytics showing different TVL to subgraph query

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, uniswapv3, the-graph

[Uniswap's official analytics page](https://info.uniswap.org/#/pools/0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640) shows the USDC/ETH 0.05% pool as having TVL = $210.20m

[When I query the same pool on The Graph](https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v3) I get TVL at $333m

example query:

```
{pool(id : "0x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640")
{
    id
    feeTier
    totalValueLockedUSD
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
    }
    token1 {
      id
      symbol
    }
  }
}
```

I also inspected the network requests (on uni analytics page) via dev tools and can see that requests are being made to the same graph url.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with TVL in the Uniswap v3 subgraphs: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-subgraph/issues/74
Due to the way subgraphs work, this is unlikely to be fixed. The developers are looking into other ways how to present this data.

Meanwhile if you need accurate TVL information excluding the fees, you can rely on other data sources: Dune, flipside, or build your own using on-chain or Google BigQuery data.

Comment: Thanks did not know about flipside but it looks good